# building Qt for Windows with msvc - Qmakespec error

Tags: windows, visual-studio, qt, build, msvc12

I am trying to statically build Qt using Visual Studio 2013

To do so, I'm following [the instructions provided by the official website](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-building.html)

1) ActivePerl 5.20 is downloaded, installed and added to the PATH.

2) The archive for qt-everywhere-enterprise-src-5.3.1 is downloaded and unzipped in C:\Qt\Entreprise_2

3) I open msvc 2013 command prompt, and change directory to: C:\Qt\Entreprise_2\qt-everywhere-enterprise-src-5.3.1

4) From here, I add 2 new elements to the path:

SET PATH=C:\Qt\Entreprise_2\qt-everywhere-enterprise-src-5.3.1\qtbase\bin;C:\Qt\Entreprise_2\qt-everywhere-enterprise-src-5.3.1\gnuwin32\bin;%PATH%

5) I define  the QMAKESPEC in order to use msvc: SET QMAKESPEC=win32-msvc2013.

6) finally, I launch the compilation:
configure -commercial -nomake tests -nomake examples -debug -static

If I skip part 5), I instead receive the

I receive the answer:
"QMAKESPEC environment variable is set to "win32-msvc2013" which is not a supported platform"

If I skip step 6, I obtain instead:
"Unable to detect the platform from environment. Use -platform commandlineargument or set the QMAKESPEC environment variable and run configure again"

However, according to Qt support center:

1) "win32-msvc2013" is the correct QMAKESPEC to use with Visual Studio

2) If we use Visual Studio Command prompt (as I did) instead of the normal one, setting QMAKESPEC is optionnal anywey, as visual studio is supposed to set the correct parameters at the beginning

So, does anyone have any idea about how I could resolve these errors?

Incidentally does anyone knows what defines a Qmakespec as corresponding to a "supported platform"?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, first go look in the mkspecs folder (from the archive) and make sure your platform is there, might not be supported or look here:
http://doc.qt.io/QtSupportedPlatforms/index.html

If your platform is supported and you have it in your extracted mkspecs folder, then no clue what your problem is?!?

Comment: well, according to the documentation, the platform is supported, but it is not n my folder.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, a good part of the files inside the mkspec folder either failed to copy when I extracted the archive, or were destroyed afterward. Most likely the latter, as it would appears that every time I try to launch a compilation some source file are erased.

The solution I found is to recreate the source file from the archive before every compilation.